# Edit SRC in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a problem with Node.js.
I want to save a link loaded in Node.js in my HTML document as a `video` element.

Can you help me with this? Can't find a solution to this...

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Testggg/style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="Search">
            <div id="SearchContainer">
                <form id="SearchField_Form">
                    <input id="SearchBar" placeholder="Type your Link here.." type="text">
                    <input type="submit" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" hidefocus="true">
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="VideoField">
            <div id="VideoContainer">
                <video id="VideoPlayer" src=""></video>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I don't have a JavaScript file because I need to include the link via Node.js.
I know how to embed normal YouTube videos with JavaScript. But I have not found a solution to Node.js.
I use the "YTDL-CORE" addon and have the direct YouTube link to the video read out in Node.js.
I would like to include this link in the HTML `video` `src`.

What exactly do I have to do?
I can't find a suitable answer.

Comment: Hello! Is this a correct restatement of the issue: "I currently have a static HTML file, but would like to use node.js instead to dynamically generate my HTML"?

Comment: Yes, I think you can put it that way.
I want to put the Node.js generated link into the VideoPlayer, right.

Comment: The link should be included in the src of the VideoPlayer and the page should be reloaded where the video is then playable.

Comment: What you've described so far still isn't clear, but I understand that it's tough to know the right words to use when you're new to a particular piece of tech. It sounds like you want to build a Node webapp with HTML templating. (https://www.section.io/engineering-education/static-site-dynamic-nodejs-web-app/ is an example of a good tutorial.)

Comment: Sorry if I can't explain it better.

I have already set up a Node.js server.

And there I get the direct YouTube link to a video output by pressing a button.
( https://r5---sn-5hnekn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?...... ).

I want to include this link on the HTML page in the src "VideoPlayer".

After some posting on the internet, I need to use Node.js to send a request back to the client to include the video.

Because I can't use "document.getElementById" as it is not present in Node.js.

Comment: And I don't understand this request back to the client in Node.js and I can't find much about it on the internet.

In the tutorial I didn't find anything about my problem....

Comment: Ok, I think that makes it clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

**If what you want to have happen is:**

1. Click a button on the client side
2. Client sends a request to Node.js that includes a value
3. Node.js handles that value and returns a response to the client
4. Change the HTML on the client side based on that response

**It sounds like the part you're missing is the client-side JavaScript.**

While it also happens to be written in JavaScript, think of your Node.js backend as an entirely separate system.

- Node.js handles requests at specified endpoints (the "backend") and responds with data
- Javascript on the frontend is used to make requests to your Node.js backend

If you need to modify your HTML in the browser based on a user interaction, you will need some JavaScript in your HTML. Your HTML file needs to include some JavaScript which will send the request to your Node backend when that button is clicked.

Take a look at [JavaScript's `fetch` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as one way to have your frontend JavaScript make a request to your backend.